# JSON Decoder not working when inserting data into CoreData in Swift

Tags: json, swift, core-data, decode

My app consists of a ProductFamily entity with a name attribute and an array of PartDetail dictionaries defined as a one-to-many relationship in CoreData. For each ProductFamily, I can have many PartDetail entities (PartNumbers) but for each PartDetail, it can only be associated with one ProductFamily. My example has 5 ProductFamilies, each with an array of 5 PartDetail dictionaries. I'm struggling to get my JSON decoder correct. It's not importing any data into CoreData. You can clone my sample project here:

https://github.com/jegrasso19/ProductFinder-Test2.git

A sample of my JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Product Family 1": [
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9013-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9104-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9105-900",
                "orderable": false,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9108-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9109-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Product Family 2": [
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9113-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9114-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9115-900",
                "orderable": false,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9116-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            },
            {
                "partNumber": "160-9201-900",
                "orderable": true,
                "pnDescription": "Part Number Description"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My ProductFamilyJSON Decoder file and ProductFamilyProperties looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct ProductFamilyJSON: Decodable {

    // Struct that conforms with CodingKey so we can retrieve the product family name as a key
    //
    private struct JSONCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.init(stringValue: "\(intValue)")
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }
    // This is the dictionary that contains the JSON data
    // The key is the ProductFamily name, and the value is an array of PartDetailInfo.
    //
    private(set) var productFamilies = [ProductFamilyProperties]()
 
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        var rootContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let nestedProductFamilyContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKeys.self)
        
        // This is where my code fails. When decoding the JSON file, 
        // it never goes into the while loop.
        var productFamily = try ProductFamilyProperties(from: decoder)
        
        while !rootContainer.isAtEnd {
            
            let productFamilyKey = nestedProductFamilyContainer.allKeys.first!
            
            if var partNumberArrayContainer = try? nestedProductFamilyContainer.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: productFamilyKey) {
                
                var partNumbers = Array<PartDetailInfo>()
                
                while !partNumberArrayContainer.isAtEnd {
                    
                    if let partNumber = try? partNumberArrayContainer.decode(PartDetailInfo.self) {
                        partNumbers.append(partNumber)
                    }
                }
                productFamily.code = UUID().uuidString
                productFamily.name = productFamilyKey.stringValue
                productFamily.partNumbers = partNumbers
                productFamilies.append(productFamily)
            }
        }
        print(productFamilies)
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct ProductFamilyProperties : Decodable {

    var code: String
    var name: String
    var partNumbers: Array<PartDetailInfo>
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case name
        case partNumbers
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let rawCode = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)
        let rawName = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let rawPartNumbers = try? values.decode(Array<PartDetailInfo>.self, forKey: .partNumbers)
        
        guard let code = rawCode,
              let name = rawName,
              let partNumbers = rawPartNumbers
        else {
            throw myError.programError("Missing Data from Product Family")
        }
        
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.partNumbers = partNumbers
    }

    var dictionaryValue: [String: Any] {
        [
            "code": code,
            "name": name,
            "partNumbers": partNumbers
        ]
    }
}
```

In my ProductFamilyJSON file, it seems to quit at defining the productFamily variable, which is based on my ProductFamilyProperties. This is apparently wrong but I don't know what it should be defined as. This is my first iOS app I'm trying to develop and learn from. I've spent a while learning CoreData and I've seen so many examples but very few use NSBatchInsertRequest and everyone seems to do this a little differently. I would appreciate some insight on getting this to work. Thanks.

Here is my CoreDataManager class, which contains the NSBatchInsertRequest for reference.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    
    static var shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    private init() {
        
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ProductFinderTest")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
        let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        print(directories[0])
    }
    
    func newTaskContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        
        let taskContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        taskContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        taskContext.undoManager = nil
        return taskContext
    }
}

extension CoreDataManager {

    func fetchProductData() async throws {
        
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProductFamilies", withExtension: "json"),
            let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        else {
            throw myError.programError("Failed to receive valid response and/or Product Family data.")
        }
        do {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            // ProductFamilyJSON uses this code
            let productFamilyJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(ProductFamilyJSON.self, from: jsonData)
            let productFamilyList = productFamilyJSON.productFamilies
            
            print("Received \(productFamilyList.count) Product records.")
            print("Start importing product data to the store...")
            
            try await importProductData(from: productFamilyList)
            
            print("Finished importing product data.")
        } catch {
            throw myError.programError("Wrong Data Format for Product Families")
        }
    }

    private func importProductData(from productList: [ProductFamilyProperties]) async throws {
        guard !productList.isEmpty else { return }
        
        let taskContext = newTaskContext()

        taskContext.name = "importProductDataContext"
        taskContext.transactionAuthor = "importProductData"

        try await taskContext.perform {

            let batchInsertRequest = self.productListBatchInsertRequest(with: productList)
            if let fetchResult = try? taskContext.execute(batchInsertRequest),
               let batchInsertResult = fetchResult as? NSBatchInsertResult,
               let success = batchInsertResult.result as? Bool, success {
                return
            }
            else {
                throw myError.programError("Failed to execute ProductList batch import request.")
            }
        }
        print("Successfully imported Product data.")
    }

    private func productListBatchInsertRequest(with productList: [ProductFamilyProperties]) -> NSBatchInsertRequest {
        var index = 0
        let total = productList.count

        let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: ProductFamily.entity(), dictionaryHandler: { dictionary in
            guard index < total else { return true }
            
            dictionary.addEntries(from: productList[index].dictionaryValue)
            index += 1
            return false
        })
        return batchInsertRequest
    }

    func requestProductFamilies() -> NSFetchedResultsController<ProductFamily> {
        
        var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<ProductFamily>!
        
        let request: NSFetchRequest = ProductFamily.fetchProductFamilyRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                                managedObjectContext: viewContext,
                                                                sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                                cacheName: nil)
        try? fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        
        return fetchedResultsController
    }
    
    func deleteProductData() async throws {
        
        let taskContext = self.newTaskContext()
        let fetchedResultsController = requestProductFamilies()
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        
        let productFamilies = (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ?? []).map(ProductFamilyViewModel.init)
  
        guard !productFamilies.isEmpty else {
            print("ProductFamily database is empty.")
            return
        }
        let objectIDs = productFamilies.map { $0.objectId }

        print("Start deleting Product data from the store...")
        try await taskContext.perform {
            let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(objectIDs: objectIDs)
            guard let fetchResult = try? taskContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest),
                  let batchDeleteResult = fetchResult as? NSBatchDeleteResult,
                  let success = batchDeleteResult.result as? Bool, success
            else {
                throw myError.programError("Failed to execute Product Family batch delete request.")
            }
        }
        print("Successfully deleted Product data.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unelated but you are fighting the framework. In `ProductFamilyProperties` delete  `CodingKeys` and the entire `init(from:)` method. The compiler will do all the work on your behalf and will throw a much more meaningful error than your *empty* literal string.

Comment: It looks to me like this problem has nothing to do with Core Data but is purely a json decoding issue. I would recommend you include a json sample as text instead as an image, it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: The full JSON file is on GitHub. If you download the project, you'll have all the files including the JSON file. When I tried to paste it into the question above, I couldn't get it to format correctly. It was showing up as a single string of data so I pasted an image instead so it would be easier to read.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I figured out the formatting issue. I updated my Sample JSON data above.

Comment: If I was wrong earlier and this really is about inserting into Core Data and the json decoding is working fine then why are you showing us decoding code and your json rather than the code related to inserting into Core Data? What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the ProductFamilyJSON decoder. In the init(), I'm creating a variable productFamilies from ProductFamilyProperties to store the JSON data. When I step through the code, it jumps back to the top of init() and never executes the while loop. Maybe I shouldn't be using ProductFamilyProperties here but defining it as a ProductFamily class object, I run into all sorts of other problems since CoreData defines my PartDetail relationship as NSSet. Can I define PartDetail as an Array instead of NSSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I was initializing the productFamily variable. I needed to initialize it with the actual values instead of as an empty variable. I also needed to move the nestedProductFamilyContainer inside the while loop. Here is the correct ProductFamilyJSON decoder file. In addition, I changed the partNumber attribute in my ProductFamily entity from NSSet to Array, which allowed more flexibility.

@vadian - I did remove the init(from:) and CodingKeys from ProductFamilyProperties as you suggested and it works just fine. Thanks for the input.

```
import Foundation

struct ProductFamilyJSON: Decodable {

    // Struct that conforms with CodingKey so we can retrieve the product family name as a key
    //
    private struct JSONCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.init(stringValue: "\(intValue)")
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }
    // This is the dictionary that contains the JSON data
    // The key is the ProductFamily name, and the value is an array of PartDetailInfo.
    //
    private(set) var productFamilies = [ProductFamilyProperties]()
 
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        var rootContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        
        while !rootContainer.isAtEnd {
            
            let nestedProductFamilyContainer = try rootContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKeys.self)
            let productFamilyKey = nestedProductFamilyContainer.allKeys.first!
            
            if var partNumberArrayContainer = try? nestedProductFamilyContainer.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: productFamilyKey) {
                
                var partNumbers = Array<PartDetailProperties>()
                
                while !partNumberArrayContainer.isAtEnd {
                
                    if let partNumber = try? partNumberArrayContainer.decode(PartDetailProperties.self) {
                        partNumbers.append(partNumber)
                    }
                }
                let partNumbersSorted = partNumbers.sorted(by: { $0.partNumber < $1.partNumber })
                
                let productFamily = ProductFamilyProperties(code: UUID().uuidString, name: productFamilyKey.stringValue, partNumbers: partNumbersSorted)
                productFamilies.append(productFamily)
            }
        }
        print(productFamilies)
    }
}
```